# saving global variable from private sheet

Tags: vb.net, vba, dictionary, global-variables, public

I am trying to send out an email with updates when the the sheet are saved. To do this I am tracking changes and then trying to save these changes as a global string:

```
Public outString As String

Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim colN, rowN As Integer
Dim changeHeading As String
Dim drawingNumber, partNumber As Integer
'Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

        'Stop any possible runtime errors and halting code

        On Error Resume Next

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            colN = Target.Column
            rowN = Target.Row
            changeHeading = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells(1, colN).Value    'Header     of the changed cell
            partNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells(rowN, 2).Value       'Partnumber changed
            drawingNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Cells(rowN, 4).Value    'Drawingnumber changed
            outString = outString & vbNewLine _
               & "PartNumber: " & partNumber & " DrawingNumber: " & drawingNumber _
                & " " & changeHeading & ": " & Target & vbNewLine

            'Turn events back on

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        'Allow run time errors again

        On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

So this piece of code works nice except if I alter several column on the same row then each change will be presented on a new line instead of the same line, Maybe i have to use a dictionary with partnumber as key to avoid this.

Then in thisworkbook sheet i have the following code

```
Public outString
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Call track
Call missingDrawings
Call updateText
End Sub
```

However now the outString variable is  , so what did I do wrong when declaring the global variable outString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two variables called `outString` one in the worksheet and one in the workbook.  You should only have one.  If you leave the one in thisWorkbook (adding `As String` would be a good idea), then you can access it from the sheet by using `ThisWorkbook.outString`.